# iPhone - iAds at top and bottom of the screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

Is this possible to put iAds at the top and bottom of the screen at the same time?

Comment: Sheesh...What did your users ever do to you?

Comment: @Stargazer712 - lol. It depends on the app. It's not always so bad. We just tend to design for one ad banner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just create multiple instances of the iAD banner object and then manage them like regular.